# Public class not public?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to use parts of this code : https://github.com/androidsrc/PdfReadWrite/tree/master/app

More precisely this part:

```
   public class PdfGenerationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String>{

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            View author = findViewById(R.id.author);
            int pageNumber = 1;
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo().Builder(20,20,pageNumber).create();
            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
            author.draw(page.getCanvas());
            document.finishPage(page);
            String pdfName = "pdfdemo";
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
            try {outputFile.createNewFile();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                document.writeTo(out);
                document.close();
                out.close();

        }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return outputFile.getPath();
    }
```

When I run the program in Android Studio I get several error messeges, the first one is: `Error:(44, 45) error: PageInfo() is not public in PageInfo; cannot be accessed from outside package`. I have changed the PdfGEneration task to public, but that doesnt seem to fix the problem. What am I supposed to do instead, and why?

The second error is that this one: `Error:(49, 31) error: no suitable constructor found for File(File)
constructor File.File(String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to String)
constructor File.File(URI) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to URI)`
What is the problem here? What can I do to fix that problem?

Comment: The issue is using `PdfDocument.PageInfo`. Looks like that class is not public. Check the code from where this class belongs.

Comment: As for the second error, look at the type of object that you're passing into the File constructor -- it's not allowed, as the error message is telling you.

Comment: But it says : "PageInfo() is not public in "android.graphics.pdf.Pdfdocument.pageinfo" so isnt that a class that should be imported automaticly? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the PageInfo constructor is private. Instead of

> new PdfDocument.PageInfo().Builder(20,20,pageNumber).create();

try

> new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(20,20,pageNumber).create();

Comment: Yes, this looks better. (1+)

Comment: Woho! Thank you @34m0